# The right way to use and update nested user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web, user-controls

Im a beginner in ASP.Net and i'm facing a problem. Here is my structure :

**MainPage**.aspx shows a modal with **UC1**.ascx inside.

**UC1**.ascx can also shows a modal with **UC2**.ascx inside.

**UC2**.ascx contains a telerik RadButton for a simple RadioGroup.

The problem is: the first click to select a radio work, but don't do a postback. Every other click afterward fire a postback, but the selection of the Radio does not work (it select and right after the update the selection is lost).

I'm 99% sure it's because I'm confused about all the telerik:RadAjaxPanel, asp:Panel and asp:UpdatePanel.

What and how should I use those elements to make my **UC2** refresh only the controls inside him, and make it refresh **UC1** controls when a certain action of **UC2** is done (close for example), and make **UC1** refresh partially MainPage when **UC1** is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `AutoPostBack` to your `RadioButton` like

`<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>`

Comment: Thank's for you answer.
I do have the AutoPostBack set to true in my telerik:RadButton radiobutton and I verified that a postback was fired. The IsPostBack is set to true when I change my radio selection :/